# how to convert unix epoch time to date string in hive

Tags: function, hive, database-partitioning

I have a log file which contains timestamp column. The timestamp is in unix epoch time format.

I want to create a partition based on a timestamp with partitions year, month and day.

So far I have done this but it is throwing an error.

```
PARSE ERROR cannot recognize input '(' in column type
```

Here is my code.

```
from (
      from raw_data
            MAP  ${PREFIX}raw_data.line
            USING 's3://scripts/clean.py'
            AS (timestamp STRING, name STRING)
      ) map_out
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE date_base_data_temp PARTITION(year(timestamp), month(timestamp)), day(timestamp))) 
    select map_out.name;
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Oof, that looks ugly. Try using this function in Hive:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp) as new_timestamp from raw_data ...
```

Or if timestamp is in `ms` instead of seconds:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp DIV 1000) as new_timestamp from raw_data ...
```

That converts a unix timestamp into a YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format, then you can use the following functions to get the year, month, and day:

```
SELECT year(new_timestamp) as year, month(new_timestamp) as month, day(new_timestamp) as day ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Saved a lot of my time. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Make sure the `timestamp_value` (here `unix_timestamp`) is in seconds otherwise use  `from_unixtime(timestamp_value DIV 1000)`

Comment: I  am getting only time till second but i want ms also . how do i do that ?

Comment: @shriyog I have the date in epoch format. The value is 1513708200000. Kindly help me out with the query to convert the value into date format

Comment: @BasilPaul As I have mentioned, you need to convert your timestamp value to seconds & then pass - `from_unixtime(timestamp_value DIV 1000)`

Comment: select FROM_UNIXTIME(cast(activation_date as bigint),'dd-MM-yyyy') from oct_pre_profile limit 5;

Comment: 04-07-49937

The output for year is weird. Could you help me out with the problem

Comment: I already suggested to convert your value into seconds `select FROM_UNIXTIME(cast(activation_date as bigint) DIV 1000,'dd-MM-yyyy')`

Comment: Okay. Appreciate your support

Answer (score 12):

With more recent releases of Hive and SparkSQL, data type of date and type casting options are available. Following should work in Hive as well as Spark SQL

```
SELECT cast(from_unixtime(epoch_datetime) as date) from myHiveTable
```

Answer (score 11):

If you need to convert the date in custom format, use this:

```
select date_format(from_unixtime(epoch_datetime),'yyyyMM') as formatted_date from myHiveTable;
```

which will return the date as yearMonth e.g. 201708

Comment: I think you may have left out one `y` in the format specifier.

Answer (score 4):

Adding this query to the list where the timestamp needs to be converted to date string yyyy-MM-dd for a string partition:

```
hive> select date_format(from_unixtime(epoch_datetime), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as day from table_name limit 20;

-- If required, remove the millis precision for timestamps
hive> select date_format(from_unixtime(cast(epoch_datetime/1000 as bigint)), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as day from table_name limit 20;
```

Comment: `date_format` is not necessary, `from_unixtime` can receive another format argument:

`select from_unixtime(epoch_datetime, 'yyyy-MM-dd') as day from table_name limit 20;`

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: @JulianQian You are correct. I used your more succinct version, and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
select order_id, date_format(from_unixtime(order_date/1000),'yyy-MM-dd') as order_date ,order_customer_id,order_status
from orders
```

or if you see any error on the same , try to use 
select order_id, date_format(from_unixtime(order_date DIV 1000),'yyy-MM-dd') as order_date ,order_customer_id,order_status
    from orders